# Application level function in PHP (similar to page load in global.asax)

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-asax

I am currently building an application in PHP using CodeIgniter.  Usually, in .NET applications, if I need to execute a particular function only when the application first starts up, I can put the code in Global.asax and that code will be executed then.  How do I simulate a similar functionality in PHP?

For example, I have a CSS file that has to be parsed server side (need to Akamai images, so the path is different in development, QA and production).  In .NET, instead of parsing the files all the time when a user hits the application, I only do it when the application is restarted.  How do I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that might be more complex than you're looking for would be to separate this rewriting functionality from your web server (e.g. have a script you run when you need to rebuild the css files, which requires manual running).

If you don't want to manually do this, you could have a check take place when your application loads, which will do the css replacing, and then set a flag in a flat-file or environment variable which your application would later use to identify that it does not need to rerun the css replace.  Just saw someone else's post regarding using Memcache.. this would work great for this flagging.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of an "application" in PHP. The script is the be-all and end-all of the "application". There's no state maintained when there's no active connection, beyond what gets stored in $_SESSION on a per-user basis.

You can force PHP to load a particular file before starting the first line of code in any particular script with the ini settings `auto_prepend_file` (and the same for shutdown with `auto_append_file`).

If you want to cache the processed CSS file, you can write it out and have some other script periodically refresh it. A cron job would fit the bill for this case.